# Looks like when I do fs.writeFile(), the changed file restarts nodemon. How to make it not restart?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, nodemon

I thinks what is happening is that for a callback to update a collection in mongoose I do a `writeFile` to `all.json` and I think that is causing my nodemon to restart.

The cmd window:

```
file saved
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
{ ok: 1, nModified: 0, n: 1 }
Anon user added to doc
{ ok: 1, nModified: 1, n: 1 }
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
listenting on port: 3000
```

I don't want it to restart when `all.json` changes.

I get a new session when it restarts and I want to do stuff with that session while  developing. I don't want to use mongo-store or session store right now. I just don't want node to restart or get a new session but I want to fix it without playing around with the session parameters.

So please confirm that because the all.json file changes that is why nodemon restarts . I know that it doesn't restart for jade or ejs files but I didn't know about `json`

Also please suggest a solution.

Comment: use `--ignore`. https://github.com/remy/nodemon#ignoring-files

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Add the name/s of the file/s you're creating to a file called `nodemon.json`, and place it at the root of your working folder:

```
{
  "ignore": ["*.test.txt", "myfiles/*"]
}
```

See other options [here](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#config-files).

Comment: Trailing comma should be removed

Comment: @TravellingTechGuy, is there any reason why this should not be working for NodeJS running an electron app? I placed the file where the package.json file is (at the root of the working directory) and although the directory with the file that will change is included, the reset of the app based upon that file change still takes place

Answer (score 3):

if you want that nodemon will not watch json file you can use also `--ext js` on start script